# HWIOAuthBundle - Symfony2 - Get email from Facebook

Tags: facebook, symfony, facebook-graph-api, hwioauthbundle

I am using HWIOAuthBundle in a Symfony2 project

How can i get the User email from Facebook, i followed [the documentation](https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/1-setting_up_the_bundle.md) , it asks me only the first time for permissions although i configured it to rerequest them. See also this [issue](https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/issues/717)

```
hwi_oauth:
http_client:
    timeout: 19
    verify_peer: false
    ignore_errors: false
    max_redirects: 1
firewall_names: [main]
resource_owners:
    facebook:
        type:          facebook
        client_id:     xxxxxxx  
        client_secret: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
        scope:         "email"
        infos_url:     "https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,name,email,picture.type(square)"
        paths:
            email:     email
            profilepicture: picture.data.url
        options:
            display:    'popup'
            auth_type: rerequest #  Re-asking for Declined Permissions
```

And the result of var_dump always returns null

Comment: Did the user approve the permission? Does the user have a verified email address?

Comment: Yes he has a verified email, and shown with the permissions

Comment: @WizKid It's weird i checked with another account and it worked, but rerequest permissions still doesn't work, Anyway thanks

Comment: Did the user decline that permission once already? Otherwise it makes no sense that you re-request it in the first place.

Comment: @CBroe , Yes the user declines permission only first time, this option of "re-request" doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of the unverified email address, Check out your email after approving the permission, and try with another account.